# Swift converting double to string

Tags: string, casting, swift, double

```
var endWeight = String(format:"%2f",weight)
```

This code was working in the latest beta, it still compiles without error but returns `0.00` in the GM.

`weight` is a double.

Comment: Sounds like weight isn't what you think it is. Have you tried logging it previous to this to find out if it has a value you expect?

Comment: Have you examined `weight` in either the debugger or with a `println("weight: \(weight)")` to verify that is really has the value you expect? Here is the deal: When there is an error, the chances are unbelievably high that it is **not** the compiler/system, it is usually **my** error, that is where debugging come in, time to re-examine all my assumptions.